# In Php, how do I set the return type of a variable using inline type hinting

Tags: silverstripe, type-hinting, docblocks, scrutinizer

How can I avoid this "error":

[image: showing error]

Basically docblocks for `DataObject::get_one` says that it returns a `DataObject`, which is true, but most of the time it is a class that extends DataObject - e.g. `class HealthCheck extends DataObject` in this case.

If I write:

```php
        /** @var HealthCheck|null */
        $a = DataObject::get_one(HealthCheck::class, ['Published' => true]);
        return $a;
```

then scrutiziner does not give me an error but I do want / and can not to write it like this.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following:

```
return HealthCheck::get()->filter(['Published' => true])->first();
```